# Check for open files with Python in Linux

Tags: python, linux, lsof

I'm looking for a way to determine which files are open in my whole system (Linux) using Python. I can't find any module that does this.

Or maybe the only way is with the command lsof?

Comment: What about this? http://www.remix.net/blog/?p=130

Comment: What do you mean by opened files? The ones which are used by your process? Or opened files over the whole system?

Comment: Well, you could look at the source code for `lsof` and do what it does, except in Python... But I'd really just recommend using `lsof`...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update as of April, 2018** for more recent versions of `psutil`:

Newer versions of `psutil` now use a slightly different function name for this, `open_files`, as shown in the following example from [their docs](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/release-3.0.1/index.html?highlight=open%20files#psutil.Process.open_files):

```
>>> import psutil
>>> f = open('file.ext', 'w')
>>> p = psutil.Process()
>>> p.open_files()
[popenfile(path='/home/giampaolo/svn/psutil/file.ext', fd=3)]
```

---

Original Answer / older version of `psutil`:

If you look in the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation) for the psutil python module (available on PyPI) you'll find a method that checks for open files on a given process. You'll probably want to get a list of all active PIDs as described in the [related stack overflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11115521/2942522). Then use the method below:

get_open_files()
Return regular files opened by process as a list of namedtuples including file absolute path name and file descriptor. Example:

```
>>> f = open('file.ext', 'w')
>>> p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
>>> p.get_open_files()
[openfile(path='/home/giampaolo/svn/psutil/file.ext', fd=3)]
```

Changed in 0.2.1: OSX implementation rewritten in C; no longer requiring lsof.
Changed in 0.4.1: FreeBSD implementation rewritten in C; no longer requiring lsof.

Edit: for iterating over the active PIDs psutil has another method (which is also referenced in the above previous stack overflow response):

psutil.process_iter()

Return an iterator yielding a Process class instances for all running processes on the local machine. Every new Process instance is only created once and then cached into an internal table which is updated every time this is used.

Comment: This is no longer valid. Since `get_open_files` have been removed. Could you please update your answer with any new functions?

Comment: get_open_files had been deprecated and is no longer available.

Comment: Many thanks, I've updated the info with the new `open_files` replacement function as of April 2018.

Comment: This only shows processes open by python session, not whole system. Is there any way to check output of `htop`

Answer (score 0):

In replacement of p.get_open_files() I have successfully tested under Python 3.7 and windows10.

```
   fileList = p.as_dict(attrs=['open_files'])
```