# `os.rmdir` not working on empty directories?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, rmdir

Assume the following directory structure:

```
A
+-- B
|   +-- C
|   |   +-- D
|   |   |   +-- E
```

where no directory contains any files (not even invisible ones). Running

```
os.rmdir("A/B/C/D/E"); os.rmdir("A/B/C/D"); os.rmdir("A/B/C"); os.rmdir("A/B"); os.rmdir("A")
```

in Python (3.5) yields

```
OSError: [WinError 145] The directory is not empty: '##'
```

where `##` is either `A`, `B`, `C` or `D`, but executing each function manually does not produce this exception. I'm aware that there is `shutil.rmtree`, but the documentation of `os.rmdir` clearly states

> Remove (delete) the directory path. **Only works when the directory is empty**, otherwise, `OSError` is raised. In order to remove whole directory trees, `shutil.rmtree()` can be used.

which doesn't seem to be the case, at least on Windows systems. The only workaround I found so far (excluding `shutil.rmtree`) is

```
def rm (dir_path):
    while len(os.listdir(dir_path)) > 0:
        pass # Maybe include timeout here to not lock the program
    os.rmdir(dir_path)
```

Is this a bug or is `os.rmdir` supposed to not block until the directory is removed?

**EDIT:** Looking at [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a6a4dc816d68df04a7d592e0b6af8c7ecc4d4344/Modules/posixmodule.c#L4167) of `os.rmdir` (for CPython 3.5 on Windows) we can see that `RemoveDirectoryW` is used for deletion. The *remarks* section of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa365488(v=vs.85).aspx) of `RemoveDirectoryW` states

> The RemoveDirectory function marks a directory for deletion on close. Therefore, the directory is not removed until the last handle to the directory is closed.

Even though I tried to make sure that there is no handle to the directory, I think this might actually be the problem (thanks to @armatita for the hint).

Comment: Its likely that your OS is [locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Microsoft_Windows) the folder for some reason. Check if there is some process happening at the time you are trying to remove the folder.

Comment: I created this directory structure on a separat partition where no process randomly goes to, I closed Windows explorer and restarted my console to make sure no handle to these directories are open.

Comment: Yes, but you mentioned that running the instructions individually will not produce the error. So likely something is holding one or more of your resources. My bet would be that either windows or one of your software (anti-virus?) is doing something in the meanwhile. There is the possibility of a bug but I do not consider it likely. Take a look, for example, at a question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114492/check-if-a-file-is-not-open-not-used-by-other-process-in-python).

Comment: Yep, that might actually be the reason. I think that closes this problem for me and I have to fall back to my other solution. (in some "crafted" cases `shutil.rmtree` did the same thing as well)

Comment: Malware scanners are notoriously bad about this. Their filesystem filter drivers break the synchronous semantics of the directory handle opened by `RemoveDirectory` (i.e. the `NtOpenFile` call uses `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT`). There should be a way for filter drivers to work transparently in this case.