# Block execution until a file is created/modified

Tags: python, file-io, concurrency

I have a Python HTTP server, on a certain GET request a file is created which is returned as response afterwards. The file creation might take a second, respectively the modification (updating) of the file.

Hence, I cannot return immediately the file as response. How do I approach such a problem? Currently I have a solution like this:

```
 while not os.path.isfile('myfile'):
      time.sleep(0.1)
 return myfile
```

This seems very inconvenient, but is there a possibly better way?

A simple notification would do, but I don't have control over the process which creates/updates the files.

Comment: how does it work on modifaction,are you renaming your file every time?

Comment: No, only the file content is updated.

Comment: Currently Ubuntu, but every UNIX system would do

Comment: What is the problem with this approach?

Comment: How are you modifying the file? Why can't you wait on a flag which will be set by the modifying process?

Comment: May be you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589407/python-how-to-check-if-a-file-is-used-by-another-application. And btw, you don't need that `time.sleep(0.1)` either if the sleep time is not much bigger. Simply use `pass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Watchdog`](http://packages.python.org/watchdog/) for a nicer way to watch the file system?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will remove the `os` call:

```
while updating:
    time.sleep(0.1)
return myfile

...

def updateFile():
    # updating file

    updating = false
```

Comment: *A simple notification would do, but I don't have control over the process which creates/updates the files.*

Answer (score 0):

Implementing blocking io operations in synchronous HTTP requests is a bad approach. If many people run the same procedure simultaneously you may soon run out of threads (if there is a limited thread pool). I'd do the following:

A client requests the file creation URI. A file generating procedure is initialized in a background process (some asynchronous task system), the user gets a file id / name in the HTTP response. Next the client makes AJAX calls every once a while (polling), to check if the file has been created/modified (seperate file serve/check-if-exists URI). When the file is finaly created, the user is redirected (js window.location) to the file serving URI.

This approach will require a bit more work, but eventually it will pay off.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `os.path.getmtime`, this would check the modification time of the file and return if it's less than 1 sec ago. Also I suggest you only make a limited amount of tries or you will be stuck in an infinite loop if the file doesn't get created/modified. And as *@Krzysztof Rosiński* pointed out you should probably think about doing it in a non-blocking way.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
import time

for i in range(10):
    try:
        dif = datetime.now()-datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file_path))
        if dif.total_seconds() < 1:
            return file            
    except OSError:            
        time.sleep(0.1)
```